# DirectX CMake includes break Windows.h

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, compiler-errors, directx

When i try to include the DirectX SDK directory into my Project using CMake, the header files in windows.h throw errors when i try to #include <windows.h> (no directx header are included before).

commands i use to generate/compile:

```
cmake -S . -B build -G"NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
cd build
nmake
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project( NisPaper )

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
IF( EXISTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/compile_commands.json" )
   EXECUTE_PROCESS( COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/compile_commands.json
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/compile_commands.json
)
ENDIF()

ADD_LIBRARY(NisPaperLibs
    gdimanager.cpp
    gdirenderer.cpp
    d3dmanager.cpp
    winmanager.cpp
    d3drenderer.cpp
)

add_executable( NisPaper main.cpp )
target_link_libraries(NisPaper NisPaperLibs)

target_link_libraries(NisPaper gdiplus.lib)
target_link_libraries(NisPaper gdi32.lib)
target_link_libraries(NisPaper user32.lib)
target_link_libraries(NisPaper Dwmapi.lib)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
target_link_libraries( NisPaper ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

#This line causes the errors
include_directories("C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (March 2008)/Include")
```

errors:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\objidlbase.h(6184): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__RPC__out_xcount_part'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\objidlbase.h(6188): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__RPC__in_xcount_full'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\objidlbase.h(6392): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__RPC__out_xcount_part'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\objidlbase.h(6396): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__RPC__in_xcount_full'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\objidlbase.h(6600): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__RPC__out_xcount_part'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\objidlbase.h(6604): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__RPC__in_xcount_full'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\objidl.h(14536): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__RPC__inout_xcount'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\objidl.h(14537): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__RPC__in_xcount'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\objidl.h(14541): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__RPC__inout_xcount'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\objidl.h(14542): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__RPC__in_xcount'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\objidl.h(14546): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__RPC__inout_xcount'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\objidl.h(14547): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__RPC__in_xcount'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\objidl.h(14551): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__RPC__inout_xcount'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\objidl.h(14552): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__RPC__in_xcount'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\objidl.h(14556): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__RPC__inout_xcount'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\objidl.h(14557): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__RPC__in_xcount'
```

And many more...

I thought this would happen because the DirectX includes override something when they are loaded in before and/or are prioritized over the windows headers, so i tried replacing the line with one of these:

```
include_directories(BEFORE "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (March 2008)/Include")
include_directories(AFTER "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (March 2008)/Include")
include_directories(BEFORE SYSTEM "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (March 2008)/Include")
include_directories(AFTER SYSTEM "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (March 2008)/Include")
```

but nothing changed.
I also tried including windows.h after some directX headers like d3d11.h d3dcompiler.h d3dcommon.h etc. hoping it would do something, but as expected nothing changed.
I would really appreciate some help, because i really don't know how i'm supposed to fix this...

Comment: Related: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9779c9ad-e20c-4d73-9703-a1a308775e4b/compilation-error-windows-7-sdk-beta-sp1-objidlh?forum=windowssdk

Comment: thanks, i kind of managed to fix it by adding
include_directories("C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.19041.0/shared")
before the directx include, but my automplete/syntax plugin (coc-clangd), which uses the generated compile_commands.json file still indicated that the error exists, i kind of feel like this is not the proper way of doing it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the legacy DirectX SDK contains a number of headers that are outdated, and conflict with the Windows SDK. In this case, when you included `Windows.h` it came from the Windows SDK, but then when that header looked for `rcpsal.h` it pulled the ancient copy out of the legacy DirectX SDK.

Header/library include order helps if you put the DXSDK at the *end*, but an even better solution is to (a) not use the legacy DirectX SDK at all per [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/), or (b) if you must use it, trim down per [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/the-zombie-directx-sdk/).

See also [Where is the DirectX SDK (2021 Edition)?](https://walbourn.github.io/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2021-edition/).

> The VCPkg version of the directxsdk port supports the 'trimmed-down' version. See [this PR](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/16010).

**UPDATE**: If you want to make use of legacy D3DX9, D3DX10, or D3DX11 for some reason, you can make use of either this [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX) or this [vcpkg port](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/dxsdk-d3dx). This works much better than trying to use the legacy DirectX SDK for anything.

If you need XAudio2 for Windows 7, use XAudio2Redist via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.XAudio2.Redist) or [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/xaudio2redist).

Avoid using XInput 1.3 as it not needed for most cases. For Windows 7 you can just use the built in XInput 9.1.0.

Comment: Thank you very much, i didn't know D3DX was deprecated, i will just move on without them then if they are not necessary.

Comment: FWIW for people wanting/having to stick with the older sdks, `rcpsal.h` was added in the April 2006 update and it was fixed "good enough to compile with the newer Windows sdks" in the March 2009 release.

Comment: There's no reason at all to use the older SDKs unless you are writing for some ancient embedded system still running Windows 2000 or something.